# Getting const property from a class with dynamic property name in PHP

Tags: php, constants

```
<?php 

   class L { const C = 123; }

   $p = 'C';
```

I want to display the `L::C` using `L` and `$p`. I tried as given below:

```
echo L::$p;  // Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: L::$p
```

and

```
echo L::$$p; // Fatal error:  Access to undeclared static property: L::$C
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the PHP [constant()](http://php.net/constant) function:

```
echo constant('L::' . $p);
```